# This code is resulting in an infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am developing a basic tic tac toe player vs player game in Java, however on running it results in an infinite loop. There are no syntax errors. I am a novice in programming, so the code is somewhat messy. Thanks.

Here is the code (the logical code, not graphics)

```
class handler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt) {
            int i = 1;
            boolean b1xon=false;
            boolean b2xon=false;
            boolean b3xon=false;
            boolean b4xon=false;
            boolean b5xon=false;
            boolean b6xon=false;
            boolean b7xon=false;
            boolean b8xon=false;
            boolean b9xon=false;
            boolean b1oon=false;
            boolean b2oon=false;
            boolean b3oon=false;
            boolean b4oon=false;
            boolean b5oon=false;
            boolean b6oon=false;
            boolean b7oon=false;
            boolean b8oon=false;
            boolean b9oon=false;
            boolean win=false;
            do {
                if ((evt.getSource() == b1) && (i == 1)) {
                    b1.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b1xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b1 && i == 2) {
                    b1.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b1oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b2 && i == 1) {
                    b2.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b2xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b2 && i == 2) {
                    b2.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b2oon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b3 && i == 1) {
                    b3.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b3xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b3 && i == 2) {
                    b3.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b1xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b4 && i == 1) {
                    b4.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b4xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b4 && i == 2) {
                    b4.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b1xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b5 && i == 1) {
                    b5.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b5xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b5 && i == 2) {
                    b5.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b1xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b6 && i == 1) {
                    b6.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b6xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b6 && i == 2) {
                    b6.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b1xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b7 && i == 1) {
                    b7.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b7xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b7 && i == 2) {
                    b7.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b1xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b8 && i == 1) {
                    b8.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b8xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b8 && i == 2) {
                    b8.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b1xon=true;
                }
                else if (evt.getSource() == b9 && i == 1) {
                    b9.setText("X");
                    i++;
                    b9xon=true;
                }
                else if(evt.getSource() == b9 && i==1){
                    b9.setText("O");
                    i = 1;
                    b1xon=true;
                }
                if((b1xon&&b2xon&&b3xon)||(b4xon&&b5xon&&b6xon)||(b7xon&&b8xon&&b9xon)||(b1xon&&b4xon&&b7xon)||(b2xon&&b5xon&&b8xon)||(b3xon&&b6xon&&b9xon)||(b1xon&&b5xon&&b9xon)||(b3xon&&b5xon&&b7xon)){
                 win=true;
                }
                else if((b1oon&&b2oon&&b3oon)||(b4oon&&b5oon&&b6oon)||(b7oon&&b8oon&&b9oon)||(b1oon&&b4oon&&b7oon)||(b2oon&&b5oon&&b8oon)||(b3oon&&b6oon&&b9oon)||(b1oon&&b5oon&&b9oon)||(b3oon&&b5oon&&b7oon)){
                 win=true;
                }
            }while(!win);
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it be an infinite loop?

Comment: I haven;t read ( or understood ) this code, but should your last `else if(evt.getSource() == b9 && i==1){` be checking for i ==2

Comment: To expand on @SotiriosDelimanolis' comment, you haven't actually posed a question here. Can you explain what it does, what you expect it to do, and what you've tried to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: It is an infinite loop because win is always false. For an incomplete question this is an incomplète answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. The expected output is a tic tac toe game. There are 9 buttons, and when you click on any one, text (either X or O) should appear. I have created a variable "i" to switch between X and O, which increases every time player 1 (X) clicks, and decreases when player 2 clicks.This is wrapped in a do while loop. It should stop running when someone wins. So I created a bunch of booleans to check whether a button was clicked and if so, who clicked it. When any winning combination is achieved, a boolean "win" becomes true, and the loop should stop running. Why is the loop infinite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping over the same event repeatedly. Consequently, the conditions never change. Each loop iteration considers the same `ActionEvent` object, referenced by the same value of `evt`. The same `if` or `else-if` clause is repeated with each loop iteration, putting the same player piece in the same place, forever.

The infinite loop begins on the first move. But the `win=true` statements can only happen after multiple moves. So those never happen, and `while (!win)` is always true.

If you want to loop within the method, you would need to get the next event inside the loop.

If you want the method to be called in response to an event, you don't need a loop inside the method.

As an aside, as someone learning Java, at some point you'll be introduced to arrays. This particular code could be simplified with the use of a 3x3 array containing values representing X, O or neither.

Answer (score 0):

Also, It looks like you have some copy and paste errors. I don't think that you intended to have

```
b1xon=true;
```

in some of the else-ifs that should be checking for Os. For example,

```
else if (evt.getSource() == b8 && i == 2) {
                b8.setText("O");
                i = 1;
                b1xon=true;
            }
```

And as Andy said, the loop in the event handler is the primary reason for the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have your GUI set up, but your *win* variable will never be set to *true*. When you click a button (the first time the method is ran), your loop is executed and the condition to set win = true will never occur. You need to remove the do while. Along with this, you need to declare your variables outside of the actionPerformed method otherwise your variables will be reinitialized.